# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I need to get the available dates from back end
lama dev course (React Node.js Booking App Full Tutorial | MERN Stack Reservation App (JWT, Cookies, Context API))
I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')
    at isAvailable (Reserve.jsx:32:1)
    at Reserve.jsx:83:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Reserve.jsx:70:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Reserve (Reserve.jsx:65:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
```

my code

Reserve.jsx file

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import useFetch from '../../hooks/useFetch'
import './reserve.css'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCircleXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { SearchContext } from '../../context/SearchContext'
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'
import axios from 'axios'

const Reserve = ({setOpen,hotelId}) => {
    const {data,loading,error}=useFetch(`/hotels/room/${hotelId}`)
    const [selectedRooms, setSelectedRooms]=useState([])
    const {dates}=useContext(SearchContext)
    const getDatesInRange=(startDate,endDate)=>{
        const start=new Date(startDate)
        const end=new Date(endDate)
        const date=new Date(start.getTime())
        let dates=[]
        while(date <= end){
            dates.push(new Date(date).getTime())
            
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
        }
        return dates
    }
    const alldates = getDatesInRange(dates[0].startDate,dates[0].endDate)

    const isAvailable = (roomNumber) => {
        const isFound = roomNumber.unavailableDates.some(date =>
          alldates.includes(new Date(date.getTime()))
        );
    
        return !isFound;
      };
    const handleSelect=(e)=>{
        const checked=e.target.checked
        const value=e.target.value
        setSelectedRooms(checked ? [...selectedRooms,value] :
          selectedRooms.filter(item => item !==value)  )
    }
   const handleClick=async()=>{
    try {
        await Promise.all(selectedRooms.map((roomId)=>{
            const {data}= axios.put(`/rooms/availability/${roomId}`,{dates:alldates})
            return data
        
        }))
       toast.success("Reserved successfully.")
    } catch (err) {
        toast.error(err)
    }
   }
  return (
    <div className='reserve'>
        <div className='rContainer'>
                <div className=''>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faCircleXmark}
                    className="rClose"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                    />
                <span>Select your room</span>
                </div>
                {data.map(item =>(
                    <div>
                        <Row>
                            <Col md={10} key={item._id}>
                                <div>{item.title}</div>
                                <div>{item.desc}</div>
                                <div>Max People: <b>{item.maxPeople}</b></div>
                                <div>{item.price}</div>
                            </Col>
                            {item.roomNumbers.map(roomNumber =>(
                            <Col md={1} key={roomNumber}>
                                <label>{roomNumber.number}</label>
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    value={roomNumber._id}
                                    onChange={handleSelect}
                                    disabled={!isAvailable(roomNumber)}
                                />
                            </Col>

                            ))}
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Button onClick={handleClick}>Reserve Now!</Button>
                        </Row>
                    </div>
                ))}
             </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Reserve
```

Room Model Room.js file

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const RoomSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
    },
    maxPeople:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
    },
    desc:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    roomNumbers:[{number: Number ,unavailableDates: {type: Date} } ],
   
},{
    timestamps:true
})
export default mongoose.model('Room',RoomSchema)
```

when I put a question mark after unavailableDates lik this:

```
  const isAvailable = (roomNumber) => {
        const isFound = roomNumber.unavailableDates?.some(date =>
          alldates.includes(new Date(date.getTime()))
        );
```

It will be solved but anther error appear

Comment: tried consoling data ?

Comment: I feel like I commented on this before; what is `roomNumber.unavailableDates` at the time of the error? It's undefined, so you need to determine why. Using `?.` here just passes the error down the line because then you haven't properly defined `isFound`.